# Is there a function to quickly find the Cauchy main value of a function at a pole?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

Suppose, `f[x]` has a pole at `a`.

How do I quickly find

```
Limit[(f[a+h]+f[a-h])/2,h->0]
```

? I mean, the expression for the function can be complicated, and changing all a's to a+h and a-h may be boring.

Comment: Have a look at `Residue`.

Comment: @Hugh: Looking in [Residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)), one understands this deals nothing with the question. I think `Limit[(f[a+h]+f[a-h])/2,h->0]` is meaningless.

Comment: @Anixx: Think of `f[x_]:=1/x^2;Limit[(1/h^2+1/(-h)^2)/2,h->0]`

Comment: @Anixx: That limit equals $0$ if $a$ is a pole of odd order and equals `ComplexInfinity` if $a$ ia a pole of even order.

Comment: @user64494 no, that limit not always equal to 0. Take Gamma function at 0 or Zeta function at 1 for instance.

Comment: @Anixx: You are right. That limit is finite if a is a pole of odd order, but  unnecessarily $0$. It equals the zero coefficient of the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ at $z=a$ in this case. This is rather mat than Mathematica.

Comment: @user64494 I am not asking abouth math, I am asking about how to better realize it in Mathematica.

Comment: @Anixx: I don't see a general formula for the limit suggested by you. For example, `Rezidue[Gamma[z]/z, {z, 0}]` fails.

Comment: I have to adjust my claim. The limit under consideration equals the zero coefficient of the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ at $z=a $ if $a$ is a pole of odd order  and all the negative even Laurent coefficients are equal to zero. In other cases that limit is `ComplexInfinity` in Mathematica notations.